Adjusting width of single table cell in Indesign CC
Is there a way to adjust the width of this sole cell without affecting the row above?


No, cells align in a grid, even if you break that cell above into two cells, they still align on the cell grid. Also if you merge two cells into one cell, the width of this will always be equal to what's on the row above.
What you can do is manipulate how content is being aligned inside the cell, using tabs, baseline shift, inset settings, or indent settings.
There are different ways to position content inside a cell, if you need help with that, please post as a new question.
